# What is the Mandarin PinYin pronunciation for the Bushou that cannot be typed?

Tags: pronunciation, simplified-characters, radicals, dictionary

I am attaching images of 部首 (Associated BuShou) from the widely used 新华字典 (XinHuaZiDian) that have no current Unicode encoding, therefore cannot be typed using your typical software on your typical computer. How are these pronounced and how are they called as 部首? Example: 亻is pronounced: rén (according to Google) and is called as a 部首: 单人旁 or 单立人. Ideally I am hoping for a unique identification that distinguishes these from their Primary BuShou.

Likewise how are the following 部首 pronounced and called: [16] , [88] 冃, [118] ⺪? The bracketed [number] being the corresponding Index Number in the 新华字典. I cannot find a translator to give me the pronunciation and cannot find how they are called.

[image: BuShou lacking Unicode Encoding]

Comment: I don't think there are Pinyin for , 冃, ⺪etc., at least no widely-accepted ones. They are very uncommon. Also I think there are no names for them. Maybe 五笔输入法 helps.

Comment: I don't think these are that uncommon, or at least not all of them are uncommon. They are part of the 280 Primary and Associated BuShou in the XinHuaZiDian and are fundamental Indexing Components in the GF0011-2009 Official Table of Indexing Chinese Character Component publication. I contacted Unicode and found at least 3 of the 4 missing (untypeable) components are on the table for inclusion in future versions of Unicode. I find it curious that fundamental components of one of the world's most widely used languages cannot be pronounced or written.

Comment: Ya, I understand. 部首 are common and are used for every learners, native or not, to learn the language. However, 部首 are uncommon that after one have acquired the language to a certain degree, 部首 won't be used anymore, since they language user do not look up dictionaries anymore, or only look up dictionaries using 拼音. And for this reason, many of the 部首 just lost their pronunciations, or they are pronounced at random.

Comment: Contrary to the notion indicated by a few people here, though it has lost its importance in finding words from a dictionary, it is still the "most" important thing to learn in order to write Chines words correctly. Note there are many 部首 similar to each other, without knowing the difference, pinyin may not help because one pinyin can bring up 10s to 100th different words with the same pronunciation.

Comment: @mika I always wonder how people look up dictionaries when they don't know the pronunciation of the character they want to look up and know of doing it only by pinyin. Surely they must do it by stroke count or 部首.

Comment: ...I mean, 部首 is a last resort if you're using a paper dictionary, and to use a 部首 system properly you need to already know the 部首 of a character in the first place. Some very common characters have obscure 部首 that I doubt the average person can guess. Personally I wouldn't be able to easily guess the 部首 of things like 串, 年, or 丸. Digital handwriting recognition, on the other hand, works every time - **you don't need to know anything about the character you're trying to look up, except how to imitate the shape.**

Comment: @mika - entirely agree. I live in China and a number of the people I have been working with can no longer identify the 部首 - sort of akin to native English speakers no longer knowing the terms of grammar. There are clearly advantages to 拼音 input systems as is testament by their dominance, yet the old ways also had advantages. As for learning a new language, there is a field of study called kinesthetic learning involving a connection with the body and learning. I am looking for this as supplemental material for a kinesthetic based Chinese language learning tool I am designing.

Comment: @joehua Thank you for bringing that to my attention - I found my previous comment incorrect! - because I have been thrown my Chinese dictionaries away for a long time, thanks to the convenience of Internet and the search engines. When I forget a character's pronunciation, taking 宆 for example, I would ask a search engine with term '宝盖头一个弓' (which means 宀 + 弓, however 宀 is difficult to type out so I choose this 'oral representation'), then I would get the answer from previous questions on Q&A forums like 百度知道 and dictionary websites. (1/2)

Comment: @joehua However, this is still done with the help of 部首! (which I failed realise earlier, because it's so natural) I never would have thought of that without your reply, thanks again! What's more, with the popularisation of mobile phones, I sometimes just turn to the 手写输入法 - I draw the character out and send it to the search engine, then I get the results from the dictionary websites. (2/2)

Comment: @joehua I also found that I have confused two interpretations of the term 'being able to identify 部首': I only thought of the ability to name a 部首 when seeing it, but I have missed the ability to tell the 部首 of a complete character - since I haven't used paper Chinese dictionaries for a long time, looking up a word firstly by identifying its 部首 became strange to me - I have already forgotten this capability, as well as its present. That's extremely surprising to me!

Comment: @JerryRossignuolo I suggest not teaching this method any more, hahaha, from the learning experience of myself, since the rule for finding the 部首 of a character is pretty complex - indeed I believe there are no simple rules, but the rules are just soooo complicated. I can still remember how dispirited I was every time I look up a character with this method when I was a kid. Today's learners can benefit from 手写输入法, search engine and dictionary websites, for example learners can draw a character out with 手写输入法 then search it with search engines, then results from dictionary websites would (1/2)

Comment: @JerryRossignuolo solve the problem. What's more, learners can use the 'oral representation' to look the word up via search engines, e.g. change the word 宆 into '宝盖头下面一个弓' (which means 宀 + 弓). (2/2)

Comment: @mika This is a supplemental tool. I live in China and am finding 2 things: many foreigners simply can't speak Chinese, let alone read or write it; and of those that can speak it okay, many cannot read or write it. They give up because they are overwhelmed. Even if people only care about conversing, not learning how to read and write is a huge hinderance to conversing beyond finding a beer or the bathroom. Don't get me wrong, I use my apps every day. But there is something about hand writing: https://www.sciencealert.com/handwriting-is-better-than-typing-when-learning-to-read-study-finds

Comment: I have also met those that sit in a classroom and go home to read a textbook or sit and play an app. And this is not working for all of them. It goes in one ear and out the other. It becomes drudgery. When you pick up a spear and go into the jungle, you get the blood flowing, extra oxygen and other stimulating biochemicals are getting to the brain. You enter a heightened cognitive state. You can't particularly do that for studying Chinese, yet you can mimic the effects through involving the activity, collaboration and competition. I am working this angle.

Comment: @JerryRossignuolo Thanks for telling me, I haven't realised the connection between handwriting and language learning, and it sounds reasonable! - since more areas of the brain are involved. I am also surprised that many foreigners in China just can't speak Chinese - I always thought they all know Chinese, haha.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, you're overemphasising the importance of this.

Firstly, the *de facto* international Chinese character radical indexing standard is the [Kangxi system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_radical) for orthodox characters, which is what Unicode primarily focuses on, not Xinhua dictionary's Simplified Chinese system (which itself is derived from the Kangxi system).

Secondly, radicals are not character components, they're only dictionary indexing tools. For example, the radical of 「年」 is 「干」, but you cannot decompose 「年」 to get 「干」.

---

Pretty much everything you've listed has Unicode encodings, and has an associated Pinyin:

- ⼹, KANGXI RADICAL #58 SNOUT, [U+2F39](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2F39)

  - 彐, CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5F50, [U+5F50](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=5F50), Pinyin: **jì**
- ⼬, KANGXI RADICAL #45 SPROUT, [U+2F2C](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2F2C)

  - 屮, CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5C6E, [U+5C6E](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=5C6E), Pinyin: **chè**
- ⻋, CJK RADICAL C-SIMPLIFIED CART, [U+2ECB](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2ECB)

  - 车, CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8F66, [U+8F66](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=8F66), Pinyin: **chē**
- ⾀, KANGXI RADICAL #129 BRUSH, [U+2F80](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2F80)

  - 聿, CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-807F, [U+807F](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=807F), Pinyin: **yù**
- ⺇, CJK RADICAL TABLE, [U+2E87](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2E87)

  - , CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-20628, [U+20628](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=20628), Pinyin: **jī**
- (Not a Unicode radical)

  - 冃, CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5183, [U+5183](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=5183), Pinyin: **mào**
- ⺪, CJK RADICAL BOLT OF CLOTH, [U+2EAA](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2EAA)

  - , CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-24D14, [U+24D14](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=24D14), Pinyin: **shū**

Now, most people won't know or use these Pinyin values, but that's hardly the fault of the Unicode digitisation committee. It's up to the IMEs to support this, and the support will only happen if the people or customers demand it.

Since it doesn't look like there is such a demand, you can infer that the feature isn't that important.

Comment: This is all nice but it is getting away from my question. It would be fun on another venue, such as over a beer in a bar, to take on some of your opinions, yet here I am simply asking anyone if they know how to pronounce and identify the BuShou that I listed.

Comment: 奧賣葛，對牛彈琴，斯之謂也 

Comment: @JerryRossignuolo I'm not sure which part of the answer really was an "opinion" - I'm merely informing any readers that come across your question, and your comments under the question, why information about detailed radical pronunciation or names may not be easily found, and colloquial names may not even exist. Simply put, radicals are of peripheral importance to the Chinese language (remember: this platform is **Chinese language** SE); they are part of an archaic character lookup system that nobody with a smartphone with handwriting recognition tools will use these days.

Answer (score 2):

There is a table of [Kangxi radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_radical)s on Wikipedia:

> | No. | Radical (variants) | Stroke Count | Meaning | Pīnyīn |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_45) | 屮 | 3 | sprout | chè |
> | [58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_58) | 彐(彑) | 3 | snout | jì |
> | [129](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_159) | 聿(⺺、⺻) | 6 | brush | yù |
> | [159](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_129) | 車 | 7 | cart | chē |

Those should be the four you asked about above.

---

Each of these radicals also have their own Wiki page.

[Radical 58 or radical snout (彐部)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_58)

> Chinese name(s):
> 雪字底 xuězìdǐ
> 尋字頭/寻字头 xúnzìtóu

[Radical 159 or radical cart (車部)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_159)

> Chinese name(s):
> (Left) 車字旁/车字旁 chēzìpáng
> (Bottom) 車字底/车字底 chēzìdǐ

[Radical 45 or radical sprout (屮部)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_45) doesn't have a listed Chinese name.

[Radical 129 or radical brush (聿部)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_129), likewise, also does not have a listed Chinese name.

But, obviously, you can add 字旁、字头、字底, on the end of anything to talk of its radical.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I am close to throwing in the towel and might make my own stab at naming them. I would go with something very similar to what you are saying. GF0014-2009 makes an effort to standardize the BuShou naming, although I am thinking GF0014-2009 is not recognized by most people outside of academia. Still it is a little elucidating and interesting in its effort. Along with 字旁、字头、and 字底, GF0014-2009 mentions appending 字框，字边，字心，字腰，字鱼 （左鱼，右鱼，下鱼）, and 省 in various circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Mou. I need to articulate that a little better. I agree with you and have been thinking of doing exactly what you are saying, although I have been hoping for a decent authoritative reference on this - which is hard to find since you can't easily write these.

Comment: @JerryRossignuolo 屮字旁 and 聿字旁 are acceptable terms for sure. You can look them up to confirm. They just aren't in mainstream usage because their use is so limited.

Answer (score 0):

I am Chinese. I remember in primary school teachers just mentioned pronunciations of some important 部首, for example:

1. 单人旁 亻
2. 三点水 氵
3. 两点水 冫
4. 竖心旁 忄
5. 宝盖儿 or 宝盖头 宀
6. 秃宝盖 冖
7. 言字旁 讠

Here is the list of all official 部首:
https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E5%AD%97%E9%83%A8%E9%A6%96%E8%A1%A8

I suggest you just concentrate on common and simple 部首 because they are important and anywhere.

In my opinion, I will identify [16]  with 冂(同字框),  [88] 冃 with 月(you can just call it 月 or 月字旁). If I were a Chinese primary school student, I would look up the dictionary in this way. However, I can not guarantee this absolutely works. If it doesn’t, try another way!

And for the last one [118] ⺪, I don’t think this bushou exists, according to the official list. Actually, every Chinese will associate this ⺪to the character 疏. Btw, I don’t know the bushou of 疏 until I search online. To my surprise, the bushou of this guy is 疋, whose prononciation and meaning are the same as the character 匹.